# What's the syntax to use @for in sass to apply a specific variable to only one page?

Tags: for-loop, sass, liquid

I'm creating a shopify template (so working `.liquid`) and I want to apply `padding-top:50px;` a div class but only if the template is loading the `index.liquid` page.

I'm thinking I can do it pretty easily by using

`@for *what ever syntax has it apply to only index.liquid* {padding-top:50px}`

Will this work, if yes, what is the appropriate syntax to define which page it gets applied to?

Thanks!

EDIT:

Predictably, after posting this i've solved the issue myself. 
The appropriate syntax was as follows: 
`.template-index &,
  .template-collection &,
  .template-article & {
    padding-top:50px;
  }`

No @for required at all, as it turns out.

Comment: Rather than editing the body of your question, it's encouraged to [add your own answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) with the solution you found. That way people searching for similar information can see the question has been answered. :)